# How do I know when a user is registering vs logging in with Devise and Omniauth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using Rails 6 + Devise for login/registration. Users can register/login with Facebook via omniauth.

I want to log **one** analytics event when the user logs in, and a **different** analytics event when they register for the first time.

**app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      flash[:log_event] = {
        'event_category' => 'engagement',
        'event_name' => 'login',
        'method' => 'facebook'
      }
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

The `flash[:log_event]` is passed to Google Analytics. My problem is that Devise seems to follow the same code path for first registration as it does for a regular login.

I suppose I could check the `@user.created_at` timestamp, and treat it as a registration if it's a couple of minutes old, but I'm sure there's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own version of [`User.from_omniauth`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jehughes/rails3-devise-bootstrap-example/User.from_omniauth). Notice the `first_or_initialize` instead of `..._create`

```
# in app/models/user.rb

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  user = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize do |new_user|
    new_user.provider = auth.provider
    new_user.uid = auth.uid
    new_user.username = auth.info.nickname
  end
  user.image_url = auth.info.image # need to update in case image changed on provider's site
  user
end
```

Then in your controller check for [`new_record?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F)

```
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

if @user.new_record?
  @user.save  # Important step I missed earlier
  # ... Do some custom thing here for your app
end

if @user.persisted?
# ....
```

Comment: When I follow your approach, after accepting the permissions in the Facebook dialog, I get redirected back to the registration page of my site. The email field is now prepopulated, although the user is not created in the database. Am I missing a step in the controller, perhaps to "save" the user?

Comment: Yeah, you need a `.save` somewhere, I missed that step, was doing it from memory. Just put it right under the `new_record?` check